# Retrieve data from restful api with angularjs service $resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try to use the $resource service with surveygizmo api.
My code :

html :

```
<div ng-app="Survey">
<body>
<div ng-controller="SurveyCtrl">
    {{survey.data.title}}
</div>
</body>
</div>
```

my script :

```
angular.module('Survey', ['ngResource']);

function SurveyCtrl($scope, $resource) {
    $scope.surveygizmo = $resource('https://restapi.surveygizmo.com/v3/survey/:id',
        {id: '@id'},
        {get:{method:'JSONP', params: {'user:pass':'xxx@xxxx:xxxx', q:'angularjs', callback:'JSON_CALLBACK'}, isArray:true}});

$scope.survey = $scope.surveygizmo.get({id:xxxx}, function(survey) {
        alert('this is ok');
    }, function(err){
        alert('request failed');
    });
}
```

When i try it, the alert 'request failed' appear in my page. No json result in the page  but i can see it in the firebug network menu.
May i miss something?
kalaoke

Comment: does the API support JSONP

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but I thought I might be able to help. I actually work at SurveyGimzo. We actually do support JSONP, JSON and XML. However; in order to request JSONP you need to specify this in the url. Using your example URL, it would look like this.

```
https://restapi.surveygizmo.com/v3/survey/:id.jsonp
```

Now when you request JSON_CALLBACK as part of the your ngResource parameters for your get action, you will get a properly wrapped object back.

I have been tinkering around with a minnie AngularJS app using SG REST api. You are welcome to take a look at my github https://github.com/sfisherGizmo/ang-app

I hope this helps anyone else who may happen across this as well.

Answer (score 0):

Survey Gizmo does not support JSONP. 
HTTP Methods which are supported by Survey Gizmo are
PUT, POST, DELETE
see 
http://developer.surveygizmo.com/rest-api-documentation/methods/

Or if they support they did not specify that in the API doc.

this is what i see when u change `.get` to `.query`

```
Request URL:https://restapi.surveygizmo.com/v3/survey/xxxx
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK
```

and if you go ahead with .get the response is

```
Request URL:https://restapi.surveygizmo.com/v3/survey/xxxx
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
```

But the response is not wrapped in JSONP callback. Though you are able to see a response in firebug network console but angular is not able to unwrap it since its not a JSONP response.

Check http://jsfiddle.net/jhsousa/aQ4XX/ for angularjs examples using ngResource

Comment: Hi ty for your answer, i'm not sure to understand...Here for getting a survey we don't use a GET method ? [link]http://developer.surveygizmo.com/rest-api-documentation/objects/survey-object/

Comment: yes docs say to use a GET method but you are using JSONP `method:'JSONP',`

Comment: i try first with GEt method but nothing appears in firebug. With JSONP method data result is visible in firebug